# Cannot Install Eclipse UIMA Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, uima, eclipse-neon

I am following the docs at

http://uima.apache.org/downloads/releaseDocs/2.2.2-incubating/docs/html/overview_and_setup/overview_and_setup.html#ugr.ovv.eclipse_setup

when I try to install the UIMA tools plugin, I get

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: UIMA Tools (includes Runtime) 2.8.1 (org.apache.uima.tools.feature.group 2.8.1)
  Missing requirement: UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.3.1 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.3.1) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.4.0 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.4.0) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.4.1 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.4.1) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.4.2 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.4.2) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.5.0 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.5.0) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.6.0 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.6.0) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.7.0 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.7.0) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.8.0 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.8.0) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Missing requirement: Apache UIMA Eclipse: uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.8.1 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.8.1) requires 'package org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: UIMA Tools (includes Runtime) 2.8.1 (org.apache.uima.tools.feature.group 2.8.1)
    To: org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 0.0.0
```

where can I install this package

`org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility 0.0.0'`

so that I can then install

```
uimaj-ep-jcasgen 2.8.1 (org.apache.uima.jcas.jcasgenp 2.8.1)
```

I am using Eclipse Neon and was able to install the Eclipse EMF tools for Neon.

Comment: org.eclipse.core.internal.compatibility was removed from Neon. The plugins you are trying to install are very old and need to be reworked.

Comment: makes sense. would this work with mars or luna? maybe uima guys need to update their instructions

Comment: the plugin installation worked with Mars, but when i try to run anything i get

`Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD`

Comment: or anything that is related to uima.tools is inaccessible for some reason. i can run uima just fine form the terminal though. its just with eclipse that i have an issue

Comment: works now. found the solution at `https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/uima-user/201505.mbox/%3C55615CE2.9070201@schor.com%3E`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by:

- **copying** the content of *$UIMA_HOME*/eclipsePlugins/* to *$ECLIPSE_HOME*/eclipse/plugins/ 
   ( where *$UIMA_HOME* is where you installed the UIMA SDK
  and *$ECLIPSE_HOME* is where you installed eclipse)
- Then running eclipse with **"-clean"**

Note: Using Eclipse neon on linux and uima 2.9